# Samsung Tizen Smart TV web app Left or Right arrow keys on Keyboard UI are not working with input text

Tags: html, input, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I'm developing a Samsung Tizen Smart TV App where I'm using a **input** tag in a HTML form. And i'm giving some input in text box and try to move cursor left and right using **left and right arrow** button from Samsung TV keyboard but it's not working.

`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name"  id="name">`

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" version="1.0.2" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="wJfsfi5g6A4.MYAPP" package="wJfsfi5g6A4" required_version="2.3"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>MYAPP</name>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/productinfo"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
    <tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape" context-menu="enable" background-support="enable" encryption="enable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to get the current position and move to current_position - 1 if pressed left or current_position + 1 if a pressed right arrow key.

```
var leftmove,rightmove;
function controlLeftArrowKeys(){
    var input = document.getElementById('name');
    if(input.value.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    var currentpos =input.selectionStart; //getting current postion of cursor 
    leftmove=currentpos-1;
    setCaretPosition(input, leftmove);
}
function controlrightArrowKeys(){
    var input = document.getElementById('name');
    if(input.value.length == 0){
        return;
    }
    var currentpos =input.selectionStart;  //getting current postion of cursor
    rightmove= currentpos+1;
    setCaretPosition(input, rightmove);
}
function setCaretPosition(ctrl, pos) {
      // Modern browsers
      if (ctrl.setSelectionRange) {
        ctrl.focus();
        ctrl.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);

      // IE8 and below
      } else if (ctrl.createTextRange) {
        var range = ctrl.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', pos);
        range.moveStart('character', pos);
        range.select();
      }
    }
```

so you have to just call `controlLeftArrowKeys` ,`controlrightArrowKeys`functions on pressing left and right keyboard ui buttons